# Matrix isn't being appended to correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

My code is for the user to create a custom matrix which is applied to the starting state. Because I want it to be able to generate any square matrix the user wishes, I have to do some funky things. My basic approach was to have the user input the different elements, which are all put in one list. Based on the position of the elements in the list, they're put into different rows. I do this using `numpy.append()`. However, it's giving the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/physicsnerd/Documents/Quantum-Computer-Simulator/tests.py", line 39, in <module>
    customop(qstat)
  File "/home/physicsnerd/Documents/Quantum-Computer-Simulator/tests.py", line 21, in customop
    np.append(matrix,current_row,axis=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py", line 4575, in append
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

in response to my `.append()` line. What am I doing wrong?

To reproduce the error in this specific code case, type "2", enter, "0", enter, "1", enter, "1", enter, "0", enter, though this seems to break for any numbers among the last four. Another note - the `print(current_row)` lines are for debugging reference. Same with the `print(matrix)` lines.

## Code

```
import numpy as np
import math

def customop(qstat):
    dimensions = float(input("What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number: "))
    iterator = 1
    iterator_2 = 1
    elements = []
    while iterator <= dimensions:
        while iterator_2 <= dimensions:
            elements.append(float(input("Matrix element at "+str(iterator)+","+str(iterator_2)+": ")))
            iterator_2+=1
        iterator_2 = 1
        iterator+=1
    matrix = np.matrix([])
    element_places = list(range(len(elements)))
    current_row = []
    for i in element_places:
        print(i%dimensions)
        if i%dimensions == 0 and i > 0:#does this work? column vs row, elements, etc
            np.append(matrix,current_row,axis=0)
            current_row = []
            current_row.append(elements[i])
        elif i == 0:
            current_row.append(elements[i])
            print(current_row)
        else:
            current_row.append(elements[i])
            print(current_row)
    if np.array_equal(np.dot(matrix, matrix.conj().T), np.identity(2)) == True:
        print(matrix)
        return np.dot(matrix, qstat)
    else:
        print(matrix)
        print("matrix not unitary, pretending no gate was applied")
        return qstat

qstat = np.matrix([[0],[1]])
customop(qstat)
```

Comment: Please include the complete error message.

Comment: @DYZ I edited to do so.

Comment: You now the dimensions of `matrix` ahead of time, don't you? Why not create the whole complete matrix ad simply store `elements[i]` into the right position without any `append`s whatsoever?

Comment: @DYZ no, not necessarily - I'm just testing this in a specific case (a 2x2 matrix). I want the code to be usable for a matrix of any dimensions, as long as it is square.

Comment: Don't you have `len(elements)` rows and columns? Or `dimensions`?

Comment: Do not use `np.append`; that is rarely used correctly. Your list append approach is ok.  But array/matrix append does not behave in the same way.  If you feel you must use `np.append`, read the docs carefully, and experiment with it in an interactive session so you know how to use it correctly.

Comment: @DYZ oh, I see what you mean...but how would you do that? You still have to append in the same number of elements in the same configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the input that you specified above (size 2 and elements of 0, 1, 1, 0), the error is coming from the fact that you are trying to append a row of 2 elements to an empty matrix. Your (empty) matrix has shape (1, 0) while the current_row has shape (2, ) if turned into an np.array.

As DYZ mentioned above, you already know your matrix dimensions so you can just reshape your input into a square matrix as follows

```
np.matrix(elements).reshape((int(dimensions), int(dimensions)))
```

Since the order you ask for the elements align with the default way the reshape function works, there is nothing more you need to add. Note I had to cast to an integer above because you parse your dimensions as a float.

Thus simplified, your code would look as follows:

```
# matrix.py

import numpy as np
import math

def customop(qstat):
    dimensions = int(input("What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number: "))
    iterator = 1
    iterator_2 = 1
    elements = []
    while iterator <= dimensions:
        while iterator_2 <= dimensions:
            elements.append(float(input("Matrix element at "+str(iterator)+","+str(iterator_2)+": ")))
            iterator_2+=1
        iterator_2 = 1
        iterator+=1
    matrix = np.matrix(elements).reshape(dimensions, dimensions)
    if np.array_equal(np.dot(matrix, matrix.conj().T), np.identity(2)) == True:
        print(matrix)
        return np.dot(matrix, qstat)
    else:
        print(matrix)
        print("matrix not unitary, pretending no gate was applied")
        return qstat

qstat = np.matrix([[0],[1]])
customop(qstat)
```

## Example output

```
$ python3 matrix.py
What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number: 3
Matrix element at 1,1: 1
Matrix element at 1,2: 2
Matrix element at 1,3: 3
Matrix element at 2,1: 1
Matrix element at 2,2: 2
Matrix element at 2,3: 3
Matrix element at 3,1: 1
Matrix element at 3,2: 2
Matrix element at 3,3: 3
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]
```

## Additional Optimizations

If you know your matrix will be square then you can deduce that the dimensions will be the square root of the number of input elements

```
dimensions = math.sqrt(len(elements))
```

Note that this probably will complicate error handling and affect UX.

## Side Note

A useful tool you can use to see what is happening is ipdb. I dropped the line

```
import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

right before your original np.append line and that is what helped me highlight your error.

Answer (score 3):

if I understood you correctly, determining the matrix dimension, appending the value from the users and then resizing the list and converting it to a matrix should work:

dimension = int(input("What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number: "))

```
ls = []
for y in range(dimension):
    for x in range(dimension):
        ls.append(float(input('What value for position ({}, {}): '.format(y+1, x+1))))

np.matrix(np.resize(ls, (dimension, dimension)))
```

Output:

```
What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number: 3
What value for position (1, 1): 1
What value for position (1, 2): 2
What value for position (1, 3): 3
What value for position (2, 1): 1
What value for position (2, 2): 2
What value for position (2, 3): 3
What value for position (3, 1): 1
What value for position (3, 2): 2
What value for position (3, 3): 3

Out[29]:
matrix([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The others have pointed out why your approach is throwing you that error. I'll just add another way that you could create your matrix. Note that you get the dimensions from the user (and it's always a square matrix) before you ask for the entries. So, you could create a matrix of zeroes, and then fill it in as you go, with the entries that the user gives you, like so:

```
def customop(qstat):
    dimensions = input("What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number: ")
    matrix = np.zeros([dimensions, dimensions])

    for iterator in range(dimensions):
        for iterator_2 in range(dimensions):
             matrix[iterator, iterator_2] = float(input("Matrix element at "+str(iterator)+","+str(iterator_2)+": "))

    if np.array_equal(np.dot(matrix, matrix.conj().T), np.identity(2)) == True:
        print(matrix)
        return np.dot(matrix, qstat)
    else:
        print(matrix)
        print("matrix not unitary, pretending no gate was applied")
        return qstat

qstat = np.matrix([[0],[1]])
customop(qstat)
```

I replaced the while loops with for loops, so that the initialization and incrementing is automatically taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so there a few different things going on here, some of which have been dealt with, and some of which haven't.

The first thing, as pointed out by @DYZ is that you're trying to append to row vector to an empty matrix. Which can be solved by reshaping the empty matrix.

The code can also be greatly simplified by to something like:

```
import numpy as np

def custom_operator(state):
    dimension = int(input("What are the dimensions of your (square) matrix? Please input a single number:"))
    elements = list()
    for x in range(dimension):
        for y in range(dimension):
            value = float(input("Matrix element at ({x}, {y}):".format(x=x+1, y=y+1)))
            elements.append(value)

    operator = np.matrix(np.resize(elements, (dimension, dimension)))
    output_state = np.dot(operator, state)
    return output_state

state = np.matrix([[0], [1]])
custom_operator(state)
```

Note that I've removed the `import math` statement that you weren't using, and that when you ask for the dimension, you should be casting the response to an `int` not a float.

It's also not really necessary to check if the gate is unitary or not. Either way, you still return the output of the operation on the state. (Unless you really want to know if it was.) If you do want to though, your current check will fail if the dimension isn't 2. A better check would be

```
np.allclose(operator.dot(operator.T.conj()), np.eye(len(dimension)))
```

However, given that you want to apply whatever gate to your state, you know what the dimensions of the matrix have to be. Allowing the user to specify that they want to apply a qutrit gate to a qubit state is only going to allow them to introduce errors. So an even better version of the code would be:

```
import numpy as np

def custom_operator(input_state):
    dimension, width = input_state.shape

    if width != 1:
        error_message = "Input state must be a column vector"
        raise ValueError(error_message)

    elements = list()
    for x in range(dimension):
        for y in range(dimension):
            value = float(input("Matrix element at ({x}, {y}):".format(x=x+1, y=y+1)))
            elements.append(value)

    operator = np.matrix(np.resize(elements, (dimension, dimension)))
    output_state = np.dot(operator, input_state)
    return output_state

state = np.matrix([[0], [1]])
custom_operator(state)
```

Also if you want to do these kind of gate simulations, and if you didn't know about them already, make sure you check out [all_close](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) and [reshape](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). They're going to come up a lot.